# Nginx location for sub-pages behind "?" url

Tags: nginx, regex, htpasswd

I'm trying to put an htpasswd only for a group of sub-pages under this url:

```
https://exemple.com/doku.php?id=staff
```

So for instance this page should be include:

```
https://exemple.com/doku.php?id=staff:modo
```

I tried to do this in nginx:

```
location ~ ^/doku.php?id=staff(.*) {

   auth_basic "Staff only";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd/.htpasswd-staff;
}
```

But there no action, even on the main page `exemple.com/doku.php?id=staff`

I tried also this:

```
location ~ ^/doku.php(.*) {

  if ( $query_string = "id=staff" ) {
    auth_basic "Staff only";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd/.htpasswd-staff;
  }
}
```

But can't reload nginx with error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "auth_basic" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf:31
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: You cannot test the query string in the `location` directive.

Comment: I tried to make this:  

`location ~ ^/doku.php(.*) {
    
      if ( $query_string = "id=staff" ) {
        auth_basic "Staff only";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd/.htpasswd-staff;
      }
    }`

But can't reload nginx with error:

    `nginx: [emerg] "auth_basic" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf:31`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself, but I think this can be implemented with the `map` directive:

```
http {
    map $arg_id $authrequired {
        default off;
        staff "Staff only";
    }
}

server {
    location /doku.php {
        auth_basic $authrequired;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd/.htpasswd-staff;
    }
}
```

The `map` directive makes nginx assign different values to `$authrequired` variable depending on the value of query argument `id`. Default value is off, and when `id` contains "staff", `$authrequired` becomes "Staff only".

Then we use this variable for `auth_basic` directive.

Comment: I can't use the http directive anywhere, even outside of server directive:
`nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/wiki.conf:1`
Same thing for map directive in server...

Comment: You need to include the `map` inside your existing `http` directive. Depending on your distribution, you may need to put it in your `nginx.conf` directly or if there is a file included in the `http` level, then you can put the `map` there.

Comment: Ok so I tired it, and it didn't work ...
I tried alos with `id=staff "Staff only";` in map directive, but nothing happend

Comment: I'm surprised there no simpler solution...

Comment: What exactly happened when "it didn't work"? And did you reload nginx configuration after the change?

Comment: Nothing happend, like I never touch the configuration. Of course I reloaded nginx

Comment: "Nothing happened" tells nothing useful. What exactly did you do, and what was the exact thing that happened, and what exactly did you expect to happen?

Comment: Ok sorry. As I explained in my topic, the page `https://exemple.com/doku.php?id=staff`should ask a htaccess password to be reach. So as you suggested, I added the map directive in my nginx.conf file under http directive, and in my file.conf under conf.d folder, I specify `auth_basic $authrequired;` in 'location /doku.php' directive, as I wrote it ...
But when I go to `https://exemple.com/doku.php?id=staff`, this page doesn't ask any password. But this page should ask a password, it's the objectif of this manipulation.

Comment: Nobody can help me here ?